Looking for a group whose fixed field is given
Given a field $K$ and a transcendent element $t$, I'm asked to find both
$$
\left[K(t):K\left(\frac{t^2}{t-1}\right)\right] \ \text{and} \ \text{Aut}\left(K(t)/K\left(\frac{t^2}{t-1}\right)\right)
$$
I know Artin's theorem, which states that given a field $E$ and a finite subgroup $G$ of $\text{Aut}(E)$, the fixed field $E^G$ is indeed a subfield of $E$ and $[E:E^G]=|G|$.
If as the title says, I could find a finite subgroup of automorphisms that fix $K\left(\frac{t^2}{t-1}\right)$ Artin's theorem would partly solve my problem,
Any help please?

Hint: Write $F=K(t)$, $E=K(u), u=t^2/(t-1)$. Show that $t$ is a root of a quadratic with coefficients in $E$. What is the other root of that quadratic? Why is it automatically in $F$? Why is $F$ the splitting field of that quadratic (over $E$). Mimic the case of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)/\Bbb{Q}$ to describe the elements of the Galois group.

@JyrkiLahtonen Is this correct? We can consider the polynomial $f(y)\in K(u)[y]$ given by $f(y)=y^2-\frac{t^2}{t-1}y+\frac{t^2}{t-1}$, as $f(t)=t^2-\frac{t^2}{t-1}t+\frac{t^2}{t-1}=\frac{t^3-t^2-t^3+t^2}{t-1}=0$. The sum of both roots is $\frac{t^2}{t-1}$, and so the other root is $1+\frac{1}{t-1}$. As any automorphism of $F$ must send $t$ to a root of $f$, there are just two automorphisms, the identity and $t \mapsto 1+\frac{1}{t-1}$, and it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$

That is the idea. Well done! Please consider posting that solution as an answer as well. That way you may get feedback from others also, and this question won't get stuck in the unanswered pile. You may still need to show that $t\notin K(u)$ (when its minimal polynomial would be linear, and your quadratic would factor over $E$. It is possible that this detail has been covered in a suitable result in your textbook/lecture notes.

Mind you, that last step is more or less guaranteed to be a duplicate of an existing question. This was the first I found. There may be simpler ones. Feel free to reuse that (at least here)!
